# DPKG/APT-GET simulated install while "hiding" dependencies

Tags: linux, apt-get, apt, dpkg, package-management

I have some `.deb` files which I am currently modifying to have varying dependencies in the `control` file within the archive. I would like to be able to do simulated installations via:

```
sudo dpkg --install --simulate ./myFile.deb
```

The install script is meant to exercise some varying logging capabilities depending on certain combinations of dependency mismatches, etc. For example, one of my packages depends on the presence of `libusb-1.0-0 > 1.0.0.16`, and I already have the latest available version installed on my test system. Is it possible to pass a flag to `dpkg` so that it either:

1. Thinks that `libusb` is either a different version than that which is currently installed.
2. Thinks that `libusb`, or any other arbitrary library/package is not already installed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take snapshots of `/var/lib/dpkg/` in the various states you wish to test, and then pass the path of those snapshots to `dpkg` with the `--admindir=...` flag.